# Button validation - Angular 2 Reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have used reactive forms in my angular 2 project. I'm trying to do button validation but facing bit confuse. Here my form contains several text fields and buttons. In my form there are two way's to give input. i.e through input textfields and upload spread sheet button.

If we try to give input from text fields, my upload button should disable and If remove data from textfields upload button should enable. How to achieve this functionality.

Sample example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnqqcx

Comment: stackblitz would be great.

Comment: you should better use `!SignupForm.valid` to disable your submit button

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha Yeah I've tried already which you suggested, but I don't think so this will work for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to

```
empty=true;
this.SignupForm.controls.userData.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
      this.empty=!res.username && !res.email
    })
```

Or create a customValidator and check is the group es valid

```
  this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
      'userData': new FormGroup({
        'username': new FormControl(null),
        'email': new FormControl(null),
      }, this.userDataValidator())
    });
  userDataValidator() {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      return (!group.value.username && !group.value.email) ? null : 
         { error: 'filled' }
    }
  }
```

or use a getter

```
  get isEmpty()
  {
    return !this.SignupForm || !this.SignupForm.controls.userData
           || (!this.SignupForm.controls.userData.value.username &&
               !this.SignupForm.controls.userData.value.email)
  }
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17llpy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for answer, Yes this is working fine but In my case there are nearly fifty text fields in my form. So is this is correct approach for that scenario to check every field empty or not??

Comment: In this case, I'll put at first in the form a radio button to allow choose to the user upload the data or fill the data manually, but it's only an idea

Comment: Ohh Okay..Any how thanks for your ans and your response.

Answer (score 0):

what you want do do is to allow user to submit the form it it is valid. That is what `valid/invalid` properties of `Form` are for. So instead

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="SignupForm.dirty" >Submit</button>
```

use

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="SignupForm.invalid" >Submit</button>
```

It works well with data validation.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdfj8z?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not I am expecting. My scenario is different, I don't want to submit a form. Test fields and button purpose is different here. If we use use textfields then button not required so need to disable. If we remove data then button should enable.